# Syntax highlighter for TinyMCE in Umbraco

Tags: syntax-highlighting, umbraco, client-dependency

I downloaded the EyeCatch Syntax highlighter for umbraco as a package from the umbraco repo.. but once I added the macro to my MVC view it started complaining about clientdependencies (on a server-side level).. so first of all.. is there any way around this that you guys know of.. or any way to debugg it?.. since the package uses a usercontrol.. is it even possible to add this to my Mvc setup?
Is there any other known good packages out there for syntax-highlighting?..

Comment: Are you planning to use this for code blocks, like GESHI?

Comment: Can you post the exception details? I suspect it is using a tag prefix that is not registered in your web.config?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box it most likely won't work with MVC. You might have to make some modifications yourself. There are details here on registering files in MVC

http://clientdependency.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MVCFileRegistration&referringTitle=Documentation